# Unable to communicate dockerized Elixir API with dockerized Node API

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, elixir

This is my attempt to see if you can help me to solve an issue I've been trying to solve for a whole week.

**Context**:

My frontend app is connected to a single API, one in Elixir. Everything works as expected.

Elixir API is connected to another API built in node for just one endpoint (we were unable to code it in Elixir so we tried in JS)

When the frontend does a request to a specific endpoint (let's say /search), Elixir should call to that endpoint in node and return some data.

Everything works perfectly on local. Both images can communicate and data is shared between them. However, when I move to the staging environment, I always receive a econnrefused error when I do the request from my frontend environment to the same endpoint.

Both docker images are connected to the same network on staging. They can ping each other and curls work between them. But when I go through the API, there is no way to get the expected data.

**docker-compose image: Node API**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: node_api
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8050:80'
    expose:
      - '8050'
    networks:
      - test
    command: node index.js
networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

**docker-compose image: Elixir API**

```
version: "3"
services:
web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - "8051:8011"
    environment:
      MIX_ENV: "dev"
      DATABASE_URL: "ecto://root:${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mariadb/test"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
      LANGUAGE: "en_US.UTF-8"
    command: "mix ecto.create && mix phx.server"
    user: "root"
    links:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - test

networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

I tried changing how the Elixir API calls the Node API, both by name (in this case node_api), by IP and nothing seems to work.

Here is a picture of how both services are running on the server (first one is node, second is elixir)

[image]

Here is the code for the Elixir API endpoint

```
url = "#{url}/search"

    body =
      Jason.encode!(%{
        from_date: from_date,
        search: search,
        to_date: to_date,
        page_size: page_size,
      })

    headers = [{"Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"}]

    case HTTPoison.post(url, body, headers, []) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: request_body}} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(200)
        |> json(Jason.decode!(request_body))

      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 204, body: request_body}} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(200)
        |> json(Jason.decode!(request_body))

      {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(400)
        |> json(%{error_code: 400, data: [reason]})
    end
  end
```

Here is the code for my Node server

```
const express = require('express');
const searchController = require('./src/controllers/searchController');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');

const port = 8050;
const host = '0.0.0.0';

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,OPTIONS');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization');
  next();
});

app.post('/search', searchController.list);
app.post('/search/volume', searchController.list_volume);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, host, () => console.log(`Listening on ${host}:${port}`));
```

(I know it should be a httpsServer but right now Im desperate and I want to see why is not working)

That should summarize everything. Please, let me know if I forgot to add anything and thank you for your time.

Comment: In the Elixir application, what is the base `url`?  (It should be different in a container vs. directly on the host.)

Comment: It might work if the network is created before running these two containers `docker network create mynetwork`. (https://www.tutorialworks.com/container-networking/)

Comment: Hi everyone! I finally found the root cause of the issue. Nginx server was not properly configured and the sites-available configuration was not pointing to the correct api. Thanks anyway for your help!